# Calculate new rows (or columns) based previously calculated rows (or columns) in same select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I am trying to calculate the yearly expected sales volumes based on yearly sales growth expectations.
In one table I have the actual sales volume:

```
create table #Sales (
    ProductId int,
    Year int,
    GrowthRate float
    )

insert into #Sales
values 
    (1, 2021, 1000),
    (2, 2021, 5000)
```

and in another table I have the yearly growth rates:

```
create table #GrowthRates (
    ProductId int,
    Year int,
    GrowthRate float
    )

insert into #GrowthRates
values
    (1, 2022, 0.02),
    (1, 2023, 0.04),
    (1, 2024, 0.03),
    (1, 2025, 0.05),
    (2, 2022, 0.10),
    (2, 2023, 0.12),
    (2, 2024, 0.05),
    (2, 2025, 0.09)
```

Is there a way to calculate `Sales2022 = Sales2021 * (1+GrowthRate2022)`, and calculate another row `Sales 2023 = Sales2022(from previously) * (1+GrowthRate2023)` and so on and so forth until 2025 all in one go within on select statement. Perhaps a loop or something? I am trying to avoid having to create a intermediary temp table for each year.

Final output should be something like this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeNnE.png). I can pivot the years to columns, if that would help.

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot work with images, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: @Stu Thanks for the guidance. Have corrected it now.

Comment: You could probably use the trick of creating a running multiplication product by using logarithms in conjunction with a windowing function on your Growthrates table (partitioned by product, order by year ASC) to get cumulative growth rates, joined back  to the original table.  Getting that all right will be a bit tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [recursive cte](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/) to calculate this based on the previous row:

```
WITH recursive_cte AS
(
    -- Anchor member
    SELECT s.productid, s.year, s.growthrate from #sales s
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive member that references expression_name.
    SELECT 
        g.productid, 
        g.year,
        r.growthrate * (1 + g.growthrate) as growthrate
    FROM #growthrates g
        INNER JOIN recursive_cte r 
            ON r.productid = g.productid AND r.year = g.year - 1
)
-- references expression name
  SELECT *
    FROM recursive_cte
ORDER BY productid, year
```

Output:

| productid | year | growthrate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021 | 1000 |
| 1 | 2022 | 1020 |
| 1 | 2023 | 1060.8 |
| 1 | 2024 | 1092.624 |
| 1 | 2025 | 1147.2552 |
| 2 | 2021 | 5000 |
| 2 | 2022 | 5500 |
| 2 | 2023 | 6160 |
| 2 | 2024 | 6468 |
| 2 | 2025 | 7050.12 |

If you don't want the fractions, add a rounding function.

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5794315c482d0e4b3e369c530e354cea) for both the above in action as well as an example that uses `round()`.

Comment: Thanks for the super good solution! Works perfectly for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding @lptr's comment-only-answer as a proper answer here as well, since it is a nice alternative and leads to the same result.

This solution creates a running multiplication product by using logarithms in conjunction with a windowing function:

```
  select g.productid, 
         g.year,
         floor(s.growthrate*exp(sum(log(1+g.growthrate)) over(partition by g.productid order by g.year)))
    from #Sales as s
    join #GrowthRates as g on s.productid = g.productid 
                          and s.year < g.year
order by productid,year
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82efc7a32c965c1bf88047cc4df19332) for @lptr's original solution.