# T-SQL The percentage increase of a number based on dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data set like this:

| Year | Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 1990 | 5.0 |
| 1991 | 7.0 |
| 1992 | 2.3 |

i want calculate percentage increase of a number based on this data.

for example: i have a input number => 100

calculated number for 100 is :

100 + 5.0% = 105

105 + 7.0% = 112.35

112.35 + 2.3% =  **114.93405**

Can i do this in T-Sql ?

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_sample] (@input decimal(29,19)) returns decimal(29,19)  as

begin

DECLARE @tmp TABLE([Year] int, [Percentage] decimal(29,19))
INSERT INTO @tmp ([Year], [Percentage]) VALUES
(1990, 5),
(1991, 7),
(1992, 2.3)

--TODO Calculate number
return @input
end
```

Comment: as query or iterative (ie with a loop)?

Comment: @derpirscher Is that possible with query ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70455334/calculate-new-rows-or-columns-based-previously-calculated-rows-or-columns-in#comment124560259_70455334

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with entirely set-based SQL.  No loops or recursion  needed:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_sample] (@input decimal(29,19)) returns decimal(29,19)  as
begin

    DECLARE @tmp TABLE([Year] int, [Percentage] decimal(29,19));

    INSERT INTO @tmp ([Year], [Percentage]) VALUES
    (1990, 5),
    (1991, 7),
    (1992, 2.3)
    ;

    DECLARE @output decimal(29,19) = 1.00;

    SELECT @output = EXP(SUM(LOG((100.00+Percentage)/100))) 
    FROM @tmp

    return @output;
end
```

Comment: Can be done using window functions also, to show the result per row. Note that this will fail if it goes negative

Comment: @Charlieface Right, or zero or NULL, etc.  You have to put in a bunch of controls to handle the general case (that wouldn't normally bother a SUM(..)), which I left out because this case was so specific.